# Access all files in directory and execute rscript using r studio

Tags: r, rstudio, lapply

I have set of files in a folder as follows :

```
nlb_1.pdb
nlb_2.pdb
nlb1_1.pdb
nlb1_2.pdb
```

How to access all the files in the folder in rscript and execute following commands for each of the files :

```
library(bio3d)
nlb_1 <- read.pdb('nlb_1.pdb',multi = TRUE)
ca.inds_nlb_1 <- atom.select(nlb_1,elety = 'CA')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make a temp vector of the files in your folder:

```
temp = list.files(path = "path/to/your/folder", pattern="*.pdb")
```

Then, lapply the `read.pdb` function to read them in a list that here we call `datasets`

```
datasets = lapply(temp, read.pdb, multi = TRUE)
```

Then you can loop through your `datasets` applying the function you like.

Comment: You don't *need* to save `list.files` to a variable, you could just call that inside `lapply`

Answer (score 0):

just use the list.files command.

```
files=list.files(desired_folder,full=TRUE,pattern='pdb$')

library(bio3d)
processed_files=lapply(files,function(x){
       temp=read.pdb(x,multi=TRUE)
       atom.select(temp,elety='CA')
})
```

the elements in the list will be result of the process from your files.